# Not able install & setup tailwindcss-rails in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm trying to use tailwind in my rails project, but I'm not able to install & run it on my system. It seems like there is some issue with the `x86_64-linux` platform as I'm using WSL to build my ruby on rails apps.
In my previous projects, I've also tried installing `tailwindcss-rails` separately following the official guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails, it didn't work and was throwing the same error.

Can anyone of you please provide a workaround or any other possible fix?

Here's the command which was used for installation:

```
rails new task-management-app --database=postgresql --css=tailwind
```

Here's the log & error which was generated:

```
Add default config/tailwindcss.config.js
      create  config/tailwind.config.js
Add default app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css
Add default Procfile.dev
      create  Procfile.dev
Ensure foreman is installed
         run  gem install foreman from "."
Successfully installed foreman-0.87.2
Parsing documentation for foreman-0.87.2
Done installing documentation for foreman after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
Add bin/dev to start foreman
      create  bin/dev
Compile initial Tailwind build
         run  rails tailwindcss:build from "."
["/home/rishabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.21-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss", "-i", "/mnt/d/Programming/Web/Rails/practice/practice/task-management-app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css", "-o", "/mnt/d/Programming/Web/Rails/practice/practice/task-management-app/app/assets/builds/tailwind.css", "-c", "/mnt/d/Programming/Web/Rails/practice/practice/task-management-app/config/tailwind.config.js", "--minify"]
/home/rishabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.21-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss: 1: ELF: not found
/home/rishabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.21-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss: 4: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
rails aborted!
Command failed with exit 2: /home/rishabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.1/gems/tailwindcss-rails-2.0.21-x86_64-linux/exe/x86_64-linux/tailwindcss

Tasks: TOP => tailwindcss:build
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: @mechnicov npm - 8.15.0 & node - v16.17.0

Comment: @rishabg-singh do you have a file named `tailwind.css` in your project? If so could you share the contents of the file? It seems that such a file has a missing `)` somewhere and this is what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to start using Tailwind CSS in your Rails project is to use Tailwind CSS for Rails by running rails new my-app --css tailwind. This will automatically configure your Tailwind setup based on the official Rails example. If you'd like to configure Tailwind manually, continue with the rest of this guide.follow the steps properly.

Comment: Hi, I've tried both of the ways to install Tailwind CSS in my rails project. You can also check my installation command I've used `--css=tailwind` both of the ways didn't work.